# Se crean saltos de linea no intencionales al ingresar datos en un archivo CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, csv

Bien, he probado de todo para arreglarlo y nada. Resulta que al ingresar líneas en un archivo CSV esta hace un salto, y no se porque. Anexo la parte del código que genera el archivo y las lineas (Utilizo Visual Studio Code):

```
columnas = ['nombre','telefono','email']
a = 0
with open(ruta+".csv", 'w') as agenda:
    
    writer = csv.DictWriter(agenda, fieldnames=columnas)
    writer.writeheader()
    print("\n\nCreando Contactos...\n")
    while True:
        a += 1
        
        writer.writerow({'nombre': input("°°Ingrese el nombre: "), 'telefono': input("°°Ingrese el telefono: "),'email':input("°°Ingrese el email: ")})
        
        res = input("Detenerse(no)/Continuar(s)... : ")
        
        if res.lower() == "no":
            break
    agenda.close
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ¿Por qué pasa?

- El fin de linea por defecto para los csv es `\r\n`, especificado mediante [`Dialect.lineterminator`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator).
- Como es casi seguro que usas Windows y en dicho SO por defecto los fin de linea son `\r\n`, al usar `open` con `newline=None`, se reemplaza todo `\n` con `\r\n`. Tal final cada línea termina como `\r\r\n`.

  Si  `newline` es `None` (por defecto) se activa ["universal newlines"](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines), todo `'\n'` se traduce al fin de linea usado por el sistema (`os.linesep`) cuando se escribe y al contrario cuando se lee. Si es `''` o `'\n'` dicha traducción automática no tiene lugar.

### La solución

Usa el argumento `newline` de `open` y pasa una cadena vacía o `\n` como argumento:

```
with open(ruta+".csv", 'w', newline="") as agenda:
```

Eso te dejará el fin de linea como `\r\n`. Si quieres usar simplemente `\n` indícalo mediante el argumento `lineterminator` de `csv.DictWriter`

Por norma general y por seguridad se debe usar `newline=""` cuando dicho archivo va a ser usado por el módulo csv, tanto para escritura como para lectura.

Ten en cuenta que no tienes que llamar a `agenda.close()`, de eso se encarga `with` por ti automáticamente, te asegura que el fichero se cerrará cuando termine el bloque, aún con excepciones de por medio.

---

```
import csv


ruta = ""
columnas = ['nombre', 'telefono', 'email']

with open(f"{ruta}.csv", 'w', newline="") as agenda:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(agenda, fieldnames=columnas)
    writer.writeheader()
    print("\n\nCreando Contactos...\n")
    
    num_rows = 0
    while True:
        writer.writerow(
            {'nombre': input("°°Ingrese el nombre: "),
             'telefono': input("°°Ingrese el telefono: "),
             'email':input("°°Ingrese el email: ")}
             )
        res = input("Detenerse(no)/Continuar(s)... : ")
        num_rows += 1
        if res.lower() == "no":
            break
```